# Asp.net mvc & Identity 2.0 - localdb for users and roles not being created in App_Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-identity

I have created a new MVC project and from **Change Authetication** option, I have selected **Individual Users Accounts** as Authentication.

When I run the project and register a user for the first time, visual studio is supposed to create a LocalDb for managing roles and users etc inside the App_Data folder., but it does not. The users get register and login but I can't find the LocalDb.

I have tested this on other sample projects and it works fine, but I don't understand why it is not creating db for this project.

Please Note: I am using Visual Studio 2017 and my project is connected to SQL Azure Database.

Thanks

Comment: Check your profile folder (C:\Users\[username]). I like to specify a connection string in my context constructor so I know exactly where it is going instead of relying on [defaults and conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592674(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene I noticed that the "DefaultConnection" connection string for LocalDb was not there in the Web.Config, so searched and found it inside "Web Deploy.pubxml" and it is pointing towards SQL database of my project on Azure. I still couldn't find the LocalDB tables (aspnetuser, aspnetuserRoles etc) there. Any idea on how to bring this database to local folder on the system? I need to do some manual entries for roles in LocalDB.
Or How can I access these tables on Azure db. 
Thanks

Comment: We keep the identity tables in the same database as our own tables by having our context inherit from IdentityDbContext. That way we can setup relationships to ApplicationUser. I'm not sure how you control the IdentityDbContext separately.

Comment: When you create a new MVC project and select "Individual Users Account" in "Change Authentication" option you will notice that it also create a "DefaultConnection" connection string to the database. And as soon as your register you first user, visual studio creates database in your App_Data folder.

Comment: I found a way around to this problem and copied the "DefaultConnection" connection string which visual studio generates from an other project and made few changes to the database name in the connection string and executed the project. I registered new user and it created the database. But still don't stand where it was creating and retrieving users from before.